# I just want to add TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_SWIPE to my instance of movieclip Rec_mc instead of stage but it doesnt work

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

```
/* Swipe Event
Swiping the stage executes a function containing your custom code. You can use this event to scroll text in a TextField or change states in your application.

Instructions:
1. Add your custom code on a new line after the lines that say "// Start your custom code" below.
*/

Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.GESTURE;

Rec_mc.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_SWIPE, fl_SwipeHandler);


function fl_SwipeHandler(event:TransformGestureEvent):void
{

        switch(event.offsetX)
        {

            // swiped right
            case 1:
            {

                // Start your custom code
                // This example code moves the selected object 20 pixels to the right.
                Rec_mc.x += 20;
                trace("swipe right");
                // End your custom code
                break;

            }
            // swiped left
            case -1:
            {

                // Start your custom code
                // This example code moves the selected object 20 pixels to the left.
                Rec_mc.x -= 20;
                trace("swipe left");
                // End your custom code
                break;

            }

        }

        switch(event.offsetY)
        {

            // swiped down
            case 1:
            {

                // Start your custom code
                // This example code moves the selected object 20 pixels down.
                Rec_mc.y += 20;
                trace("swipe down");
                // End your custom code
                break;

            }
            // swiped up
            case -1:
            {

                // Start your custom code
                // This example code moves the selected object 20 pixels up.
                Rec_mc.y -= 20;
                trace("swipe up");
                // End your custom code
                break;

            }
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The gesture events are not localized within a particular MC located on the stage, because a gesture can take up the whole screen or dimensions of the sensor. So, be a good programmer and register the listener to `stage`, and parse gestures in regard to your application's current state.

```
if (stage) init(); else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,init);
function init(e:Event=null):void {
    removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,init);
    stage.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_SWIPE, fl_SwipeHandler);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment, is that any way to swipe the movieclip to perform certain action?

Comment: So, you want to register the gesture location, and determine what object is swiped by that location? I don't expect it's possible at all, because gestures are too big to logically determine what object are they aimed to affect. I'd say go taps and listen for `MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAG` events then.

Comment: Yes, build one swipe and touch interpreter using the stage.  You can use touch events on buttons or clips too to check to see if something is being touched or tapped.